# Install Ubuntu 18.04 on HP OMEN

Tags: system-installation, 18.04, hp

While I install Ubuntu 18.04 on my HP OMEN15T gaming laptop, it just works a few seconds and then the screen freezes and I can't click anything. I have tried to use a another USB, but it still has the same error.

Comment: Same Problem with a new 17-ap0xx Omen X - arghhh.  I have never had any problems installing ubuntu for 10 years on over 100 pcs - weird

Comment: Late answer to this question but I had the same problem. This problem seems to stem from the fact that gaming laptops rely on nvidia graphics cards for the display and uses nvidia graphics drivers so there seems to be a conflict with nvidia graphics drivers and the ubuntu noveau drivers. The solution is to black-list the noveau drivers and install the nvidia ones . I used this as a guide : https://gist.github.com/mari-linhares/cef4cb3440408e44963d1447a7db5ae0  . Note: make sure to use the correct nvidia driver for your card(it may not be the 396 used in the solution mine was 390 for the 1050Ti